# Which noun would you use to complete this sentence?

Tags: word-request

> The professor is always surrounded and approached by
>   many students who would like to do research with him. He also seems to
>   enjoy such __ very much, and doesn't like other students who don't surround and approach him as often.

Which noun would you used to fill in the blank, to summarize the behaviour of the students that often surround and approach the professor? Thanks!

Comment: I'd use *attention*  although I'd change *such* to *this*

Comment: Thanks, @Jim. Why this not such?

Comment: It's not a construction I think many native speakers would use-  *such* is not wrong but *this* just flows off the tongue better in my opinion.  It may have to do with the close repetition of the *ch/sh* sound in 'su **ch** ' and 'atten **ti** on'

Comment: such means "that type of attention", whereas "this" just means "the attention". The real problem is the word "also"; it is superfluous and does not refer to anything. "also" means in addition to: in addition to what?

Comment: @Kaz- Agreed. I think in this instance though, *that type of attention* and *the attention just mentioned* amount to the same thing.

Comment: *also* may suggest that the professor **also** enjoys **as the students do** (an approach and gathering).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many words you can put in there. Not only "attention", but, say, "flattery". If the writer or speaker dislikes the situation (which is likely here, because the paragraph notes that the professor dislikes those who do not approach him this way), and if the writing is informal, then derogatory slang words such as "sucking up" and "brown nosing".  Can be used. There is also the fancy word of Greek origin via Latin: "sycophancy".

To say that the professor enjoys the sycophancy or sucking up is a kind of sarcastic viewpoint. When speak about someone else enjoying something, we usually take that person's point of view of the subject. But if we use a negative word, then that is sarcasm. For instance, "John sure enjoys that horse piddle that passes for beer around here." [Though I began talking about what John enjoys, I'm taking **my** view on his enjoyment, not his, and I look down on John for liking this bad beer.]

> That group of brown-nosing sycophants is sucking up to the professor again, as usual, and, true to his nature, he's eating it up like a moron.

Answer (score 0):

Although the paragraph notes that the professor dislikes those who do not approach him this way, a more neutral term would be "*interactions*."

> **interaction** *definition*
>
> NOUN
> singular: interaction
> plural: **interactions**
>
> 1. the activity of being with and talking to other people, and the way that people react to each other

The American English definition of interaction from [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/interaction)